# Multiple images opened in photoshop save for web different filesizes according to the filenames

Tags: javascript, batch-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have several images opened at once in photoshop but they need to be checked accordingly with the filename and saved out accordingly. This script seems to run with one image but the other images opened do not work. Thank you!

**Problem 1:** Border Added needs to be black not white.

**Problem 2:** Needs to work with all images opened. currently works with the first image opened not the rest of the images.

### **This is what the script does**

Name.SizexSize.png -> add 1px border -> JPG 59kb -> Save for web + no prompt. Name.SizexSize.png -> add 1px border -> JPG 39kb -> Save for web + no prompt. Overwrite originals.

```
for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
activeDocument = documents[i]; //will change active document to one of 
the opened

var docNameSize = activeDocument.name.split(".")[1].split("x"); //will 
get you [Size, Size] from Name.SizexSize.png;
for (var k = 0; k < docNameSize.length; k++) docNameSize[k] = 
parseInt(docNameSize[k]); //will convert [Size, Size] to numbers
}


 for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
 activeDocument = documents[i]; //will change active document to one 
 of the opened

 var docNameSize = activeDocument.name.split(".")[1].split("x"); 
 //will get you [Size, Size] from Name.SizexSize.png;
 for (var k = 0; k < docNameSize.length; k++) docNameSize[k] = 
 parseInt(docNameSize[k]); //will convert [Size, Size] to numbers
 }

 selectAll()
 contractSelection(1)
 invertSelection()
 fillWithWhiteColor()
 deselect()

 function cTID(s)
 {
  return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
 };

 function sTID(s)
 {
 return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
 };

 function selectAll()
 {
 var desc26 = new ActionDescriptor();
 var ref2 = new ActionReference();
 ref2.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('fsel')); 
 desc26.putReference(cTID('null'), ref2);
 desc26.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Al  '));
 executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc26, DialogModes.NO);
 }

 function contractSelection(_value)
 {
var desc30 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc30.putUnitDouble(cTID('By  '), cTID('#Pxl'), _value);
desc30.putBoolean(sTID('selectionModifyEffectAtCanvasBounds'), true);
executeAction(cTID('Cntc'), desc30, DialogModes.NO);
};

function invertSelection()
{
executeAction(cTID('Invs'), undefined, DialogModes.NO);
};

function fillWithWhiteColor()
{
var desc35 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc35.putEnumerated(cTID('Usng'), cTID('FlCn'), cTID('Clr '));
var desc36 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc36.putUnitDouble(cTID('H   '), cTID('#Ang'), 0.000000);
desc36.putDouble(cTID('Strt'), 0.000000);
desc36.putDouble(cTID('Brgh'), 100.000000);
desc35.putObject(cTID('Clr '), cTID('HSBC'), desc36);
desc35.putUnitDouble(cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), 100.000000);
desc35.putEnumerated(cTID('Md  '), cTID('BlnM'), cTID('Nrml'));
executeAction(cTID('Fl  '), desc35, DialogModes.NO);
};

function deselect()
{
var desc38 = new ActionDescriptor();
var ref3 = new ActionReference();
ref3.putProperty(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('fsel'));
desc38.putReference(cTID('null'), ref3);
desc38.putEnumerated(cTID('T   '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('None'));
executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc38, DialogModes.NO);
};
saveJPG(
{
  path: activeDocument.path,
  maxSize: 50 //size in kbs
 })

 function saveJPG(_data)
 {
 if (_data.path == undefined) return false;
_data.name = _data.name == undefined ? activeDocument.name : _data.name;
_data.quality == undefined && _data.quality = 75;

if (!new Folder(_data.path).exists)
{
    alert("Output path doesn't exist!"); //you can add a function to create a path if needed
    return false
}

var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(),
    jpgFile = new File(_data.path + '/' + getName(_data.name) + '.jpg');

options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
options.quality = _data.quality;
activeDocument.exportDocument(jpgFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

if (_data.maxSize != undefined)
{
    var ms = _data.maxSize * 1000;
    if (jpgFile.length > ms)
    {
        if (!jpgFile.remove())
        {
            alert('Save file is locked, please make sure it\'s not opened anywhere');
            return
        };
        saveJPG(
        {
            path: _data.path,
            name: _data.name,
            maxSize: _data.maxSize,
            quality: _data.quality - 2
        });
    }
};

function getName(fullName)
{
    var temp = String(fullName).split("/"),
        fullName = temp.pop();
    return fullName.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, "")
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through your documents to get their names, but then you do all the routine for creating a border only *once*. All these `selectAll()`, `contractSelection()` and others should be inside your loop. If you're not familiar with Javascript I'd suggest to take a course on codeacademy for example: i'ts free and won't take a lot of time.

To change color to black replace this line `desc36.putDouble(cTID('Brgh'), 100.000000);` with `desc36.putDouble(cTID('Brgh'), 0);`

Comment: thanks !!! it seems to be working now but it gets stuck on the second image its processing and then just keeps looping and processing that image. ?..